# Different height of a video with 100% width in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

For a video with a 100% width, the jquery height() function (***edit***: innerHeight() and outerHeight() too) returns different number in different browsers.

See http://www.bootply.com/iNuBWZeWCx

My resolution is 1920x1080 but the browsers return different numbers for any specific resolution. The true height of the video on my resolution with browser window maximized is 1047px

- Chrome 48.0.2564.109 m: almost always outputs **952**, rarely **1047** though I could not detect why it changes, I'm now refreshing it but it's staying at 952...
- Firefox 44.0.2: consistently outputs **1047**
- IE Edge 11.103.10586.0: consistently outputs **952**

Why is Chrome + IE outputting 952? How did they get that number? And how do I get the right height?

Code below as requested...

```
<p id="videoheight"></p>
<video id="bgvideo" style="width:100%;">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#videoheight").text($("#bgvideo").innerHeight());
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

- IE Edge in the DOM Explorer shows 1903x1046.65
- Firefox Inspector: 1903x1046.65
- Chrome Developer Tools: 1903x1047

Comment: I've added some css: http://www.bootply.com/JHJuzhEmT8 . Now in IE, FF and Chrome height is same.

Comment: Bob Sponge: it does not to me...though I disabled addons and firefox now shows 1047 while chrome and IE still 952 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be this is a timing issue. Since your video might not be loaded yet, and the dimensions of your video file are still unknown at the time you request your height.

You should wait for the [loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata) event.

```
$(function () {
    $("#bgvideo").bind("loadedmetadata", function () {
         $("#videoheight").text($(this).innerHeight());
    });
});
```

Comment: This works in IE and Chrome but Firefox refuses to even start that event http://www.bootply.com/Vp7xHbDLR4 :(

At least in bootply...

Comment: nevertheless I'm accepting it, I didn't know about this event

Answer (score 1):

My resolution is 1920x1080 too, use "width:109.99%". http://www.bootply.com/3cCMYE77fs

```
<p id="videoheight"></p>
<video style="width:109.99%" id="bgvideo" controls="">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: And I rejected it. This is hardly a solution - the video must be 100% wide not 109.99% wide to fix the height. This does not fix the problem.